# Не работает req.on('data', () =>{}) на nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, requests, postman

Вот простейший код на ноде, стоит 16.13.0 LTS версия:

```
const { createServer } = require('http');

const PORT = 3000;

const server = createServer((req, res) => {
let body = '';

req.on('data', (chunk) => {
    body = chunk.toString();
});

req.on('end', () => {
    const parsedBody = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log('Parsed body', parsedBody);
    const propsCount = Object.keys(parsedBody).length;
    console.log('Props count', propsCount);
    res.writeHead(
        200,
        {
            'Content-type': 'text/plain'
        }
    )
    .end(`Body from request has been succesfully accepted and parsed. It has ${propsCount} props`);
});
});

server.listen(PORT, () => {
console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Через **Postman** отправляю POST запрос с массивом в **JSON** формате:

```
{
    "dsad": "string data",
    "prid": true,
    "prdop3": "1337"
}
```

Приходит ошибка следующая:

```
undefined:1
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

Перед **parsedBody** вставлял **console.log(body)**, чтобы взглянуть что там в переменной, а там пусто и соответсвенно такая ошибка.
Не работает именно та часть, где идет обработка req.on('data', (chunk) , я не понимаю в  чем проблема, помогите пж.

Comment: Я вам уже два раза написал: код работает. Разберитесь что у вас там с постманом.

Comment: Для начала выведите req.method и req.headers

Comment: @AlexeyTen написал console.log(req.method,req.headers), после объявления переменной body и результат  - POST { 'content-type': 'application/json' }. Вроде всё ок(

Comment: А content-length где??

Comment: @AlexeyTen а он для чего, простите) я только только познакомился с постман

Comment: Ну серверу же нужно знать сколько данных он должен получить. В отсутствии заголовка нода считает что данных нет и даже не пытается читать тело запроса. Почему постман сам не вычисляет и не отправляет размер я не знаю. Возможно вы что-то криво в нём настроили

Comment: @AlexeyTen вся проблема, как вы и сказали была в content-length ,я добавил и этот простецкий код наконец-то заработал и я теперь узбагоился)
Спасибо большое, Алексей!
Просто добавьте ответ и спасибо хоть как-то дам свой.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, с какой бы стати этому коду работать?

Comment: @Qwertiy а чо бы нет? Хотя и с глюками конечно.

Answer (score 0):

У меня в chunk ничего не было из-за того, что инпутам формы не дал name. Но форма отправлялась стандартным способом html.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> body = chunk.toString();
> ```

Во-первых, за это надо руки отрывать. Не все же в США живут.

Во-вторых, предполагалось `+=`, а не `=`.

А правильно делать так:

```
var chunks = []

request.on('data', chunk => chunks.push(chunk))

request.on('end', () => {
  var body = Buffer.concat(chunks) + ""
```

> Но форма отправлялась стандартным способом html.

html вообще не отправляет формы в json, насколько я помню.